# openLDAP post-read control: value is absent

Tags: ldap, openldap

I'm trying to implement LDAP post-read control in my LDAP client application, and currently I can't figure out exactly how packet with controls has to be coded, so that openLDAP can recognize it. Being more specific - I have problem with controlValue field of postRead control.

According to RFC4527 - "controlValue, an OCTET STRING, contains a BER-encoded AttributeSelection [RFC4511],".
From RFC4511 -

```
AttributeSelection ::= SEQUENCE OF selector LDAPString
                        -- The LDAPString is constrained to
                        -- <attributeSelector> in Section 4.5.1.8
```

So, this means (if I get it right) that controlValue is a "SEQUENCE OF LDAPStrings", and each LDAPStrings is a OCTET STRING containing name of some attribute. However, it seems that I've misunderstanded something, but can't figure out what.

Here is packet, that I send to openLDAP server:
   [image: packet being sent]
Here is DUMP of packet, that I send to openLDAP server:
[image: dump of packet being sent]
Below is the answear of server:
[image: packet received]

What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured it out. According to RFC 4511:

```
Control ::= SEQUENCE {
     controlType             LDAPOID,
     criticality             BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE,
     controlValue            OCTET STRING OPTIONAL }
```

And from RFC 4527:

```
controlValue, an OCTET
   STRING, contains a BER-encoded AttributeSelection
```

Wich means that control value is not a "SEQUENCE OF LDAPStrings", but a OCTET STRING, wich contains that sequence. This solved the problem.